# hightChart print 'noData' message

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I use the library hightChart for build some graph and i want to put a message when their is no data in my chart so i have this javascript code :

```
   statChart = new Highcharts.Chart
    ({
            lang:
            {
                noData : "no data",
            },
            chart:
            {
                renderTo: 'chart_container',
                type: 'line',
                marginRight: 130,
                marginBottom: 25
            },
            title:
            {
                text: 'Graphique',
                x: -20
            },
            subtitle:
            {
                x: -20
            },
            xAxis:
            {
                categories:['Juin', 'Juillet', 'Aout', 'Septembre', 'Octobre', 'Novembre', 'Décembre', 'Janvier', 'Février', 'Mars', 'Avril', 'Mai']
            },
            yAxis:
            {
                title:
                {
                    text: ''
                },
                plotLines: 
                [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                }]
            },
            legend:
            {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                x: -10,
                y: 100,
                borderWidth: 0,
            },
            credits :
            {
                enabled : false
            }
});
```

And after i add some data with javascript like that :

```
newSerie = statChart.addSeries(
    {
        name : nameGraph,
        data : []
    });
```

But i never arrive to print the message who say no data and i really don't understand why because on all the exemple i find their is nothing special to do for print this message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need also include the no-data-to-display.js:http://code.highcharts.com/modules/no-data-to-display.js